Overlaying images due to differences in screen resolution on Android Studio (Kotlin)
I got one big problem with overlaying images due to differences in screen resolution (meaning I use pixel 7 phone aligned, but it's pixel 3 on smaller screen misaligned). And I already used percentage based positioning of the layout. Is there a way to always ensure the circleImageView always overlay at the correct location above templateLayout?
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/templateContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/newjobcardtabLayout"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/templateLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/veh_cond_template"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline_circleImageView_x"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.235" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline_circleImageView_y"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.275" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_circle"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_circleImageView_x"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_circleImageView_y" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Unable to overlay image over image properly with different resolutions

Could you add an image for better understanding?
